# How come it's possible to malloc() an infinite amount of memory in C?

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

I was trying to induce an ENOMEM error just to satisfy my own curiosity, so I decided to run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    double POS_INF = 1.0/0.0;
    char *s = malloc(POS_INF);
}
```

To my suprise, it compiled and ran successfully.  Shouldn't there have been an ENOMEM error or some other type of error?

I decided to run valgrind to see what was going on. On the sixth line of the valgrind output, it showed the following:

`Argument 'size' of function malloc has a fishy (possibly negative) value: -9223372036854775808`

This output really confuses me. Does it think that the `POS_INF` variable, which is meant to be equal to positive infinity, is actually `-9223372036854775808`?

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `malloc` takes a `size_t` argument. How can that be infinity? The decimal value you show is `0x8000000000000000` more meaningful in hex.

Comment: You provide a `double` argument to `malloc` which requires a `size_t` argument. What do you expect? The double argument is converted to `size_t` which results in some nonsense value which is then used by `malloc` etc. BTW did you check the value of `s` after the call to `malloc`?

Comment: You could try to assign `POS_INF` to a `size_t` variable and see what result is created.

Comment: (1) There is no such integer as infinity. (2) What do you mean by "ran successfully"? That it didn't crash nor orinted an error message? That's right, `malloc` shouldn't do either of this, regardless of the argument.

Comment: Some systems do allow you to allocate vast amounts of memory, which isn't committed until you actually use it.

Comment: Some operating systems are configured to overcommit. `malloc` will succeed, but you'll get a segfault if you actually try to use the memory.

Comment: *Shouldn't there have been an ENOMEM error or some other type of error?* Quite possibly, but the code you've shown doesn't check for that!

Comment: @SteveSummit Oh. How do I check for it then?

Comment: A simple `if(s == NULL) { perror("malloc"); exit(1); }` would be a good start.

Comment: The C standard doesn't require `malloc` to set `errno` when it fails, but the standards for the operating system might require it. (Any standard library function is allowed to set `errno` to a non-zero value whether or not it fails.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `malloc()` as defined in `<stdlib.h>` takes an argument of type `size_t`. Passing a `double` invokes an implicit conversion from `double` to `size_t`, which is only defined if `double` value is finite and the integral part in within the range of type `size_t`.

Converting `Infinity` is hence undefined. Note that computing `1.0/0.0` is not defined on all platforms, but does evaluate to a positive infinity on IEEE-754 conforming architectures such as most modern systems.

As a consequence, your code has undefined behavior. It seems converting a positive infinite value (if your system supports it) to the type `unsigned long` for which `size_t` is a typedef on your system produces the value `0x8000000000000000` (`9223372036854775808` in decimal, reported as `-9223372036854775808` if converted as a signed value), which `malloc()` reports as *fishy*... I tend to agree :). Other systems might behave differently, possibly terminating your program abruptly.

Malloc detects this argument value as *fishy* because programmers passing negative values to `malloc()` actually pass huge unsigned values as converted implicitly to unsigned type `size_t`. This explains the error message and the signed conversion. It must be a common enough mistake to warrant issuing a runtime warning to `stderr`, but it leaves the user clueless about something of interest only to the programmer.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    double POS_INF = 1.0/0.0;
    char *s = malloc(POS_INF);
    printf("(size_t)%g -> %zu\n", POS_INF, (size_t)POS_INF);
    printf("malloc(%zu) -> %p\n", (size_t)POS_INF, (void *)s);
    if (s == NULL) {
        printf("errno=%d %s (%s)\n", errno,
               errno == ENOMEM ? "(ENOMEM)" : "",
               strerror(errno));
    }
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Running this program multiple times gives a good illustration of *undefined behavior*: the conversion gives different values in successive occurrences (but produces a value small enough for `malloc()` to allocate):

```
chqrlie$ make 220929-malloc
clang -O3 -Weverything -Wno-padded -o 220929-malloc 220929-malloc.c
220929-malloc.c:8:22: warning: implicit conversion turns floating-point number into integer: 'double' to 'unsigned long'
      [-Wfloat-conversion]
    char *s = malloc(POS_INF);
              ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
chqrlie$ ./220929-malloc
(size_t)inf -> 4194304
malloc(3520768) -> 0x7fbc69400350
```

Comment: Interesting. What is normally the maximum amount of memory you can allocate with malloc()? Not like in the undefined behavior case, but in normal circumstances.

Comment: @MathGeek the theoretical maximum is the maximum value a `size_t` can take. Practically it is much less, but the limit depends on the platform. Do some experimentation, e.g allocating/freeing larger and larger chunks of memory until `malloc` returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

> How come it's possible to malloc() an infinite amount of memory in C?

It is not possible to `malloc` an infinite amount of memory in C.

Firstly, remember that programming in general (and C in particular) is not pure mathematics.  The concept of "infinity" does not necessarily even exist.

It's true, IEEE-754 has a distinct and meaningful value for "infinity".  (It even has two: positive and negative.)  And, it's also true, the expression `1.0/0.0` will generate this value.

However, *`malloc` does not take a double*.  So the concept, "`malloc` an infinite amount of memory" is quiet meaningless.  `malloc` actually takes an argument of type `size_t`, so the only values you can (attempt to) `malloc` are values that can be expressed as type `size_t`.

Now, C supports implicit conversions, including from `double` to `size_t`, so the compiler will *attempt* to do that.  But I don't think the conversion of `double` to `size_t` is perfectly defined (or can be).  I can't remember, but I'm pretty sure the rule is that if the truncated `double` value can't be properly represented as a value of type `size_t`, the result is undefined.  So `malloc(1024.0)` is fine, and `malloc(1024.1)` is probably also fine, but `malloc(1e100)` is *not* fine, and `malloc(1.0/0.0)` is right out.

And then, finally, you expressed surprise that `malloc` didn't fail, but in fact, maybe it did: since your program didn't check, you have no way of knowing!

The last line of your test program was

```
char *s = malloc(POS_INF);
```

So you assign `malloc`'s result to a pointer variable `s`, but then throw it away and exit.  Since you don't do anything with `s`, it wouldn't be too wrong for the compiler to throw away the whole line — that is, to not call `malloc` at all — since you obviously didn't care about the return value, and would have no way of knowing if the compiler cheated and didn't call it.

Suppose you add the lines

```
if(s == NULL) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(1);
}
```

at the end of the program.  *Now* you're actually in a position to determine whether `malloc` failed.

After that there are three possibilities:

1. `malloc` fails, because the converted `size_t` value (whatver it is) asks for more memory than is available.
2. `malloc` succeeds, because the converted `size_t` value (whatver it is) asks for memory that *is* available.
3. `malloc` seems to succeed, because although the converted `size_t` value asks for more memory than is available, you're on a system that [overcommits memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment), and only fails when you try to use it.

So to really see what's going on, you might want to change the code to

```
size_t sz = POS_INF;
char *s = malloc(sz);
if(s == NULL) {
    printf("can't malloc %zu bytes: %s\n", sz, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

so that you can actually see what `size_t` value you got.  And to be really sure, you can follow that up with

```
s[0] = 1;
s[sz/2] = 2;
s[sz-1] = 3;
```

to see if you actually got memory you can use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, according to chqrlie, the double is automatically converted to size_t. What I do not know is if this conversion is well defined

Comment: You should mention that a `double` provided to a function expecting a `size_t` is implicitely converted.

Comment: @MathGeek it depends, the answer to this is in chqrlie's answer. But anyway, it is pretty pointless to pass a `double` to `malloc`, IMO this is a serious program design error.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes I just realised it. I commented when the answer had not been edited yet to include chqrlie's answer. Apologies.

Comment: Very interesting. Turns out malloc did fail. Furthermore, when I printed out ```s```, I realised it was a NULL value, which signifies that something did go wrong.

Comment: @MathGeek well, it's not really astonishing that `malloc` fails if you call it with a weird (negative here) size.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, in case memory allocation functions (`malloc()` and family) fails to allocate the memory, they return a null pointer. They don't create some fault or error on their own. You need to check for the validity (non-null pointer in this case) after the call to a(ny) library function as a best practice.

That said, `malloc()` accepts an argument of type `size_t`. Passing a double is not allowed.

Comment: *Passing a double is not allowed*... why not? the `double` value is implicitly converted to `size_t`, and `malloc()` will try and allocate the corresponding number of bytes. Passing a `double` is *fishy* nonetheless.

Comment: @chqrlie Is the conversion well-defined?

Comment: **6.3.1.4 Real  floating and integer [conversions]**
*When a finite value of standard floating type is converted to an integer type other than `bool`, the fractional part is discarded (ie: the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.* note: *The remaindering operation performed when a value of integer type is converted to unsigned type need not be performed when a value of real floating type is converted to unsigned type. Thus, the range of portable real floating values is (`−1`, `Utype_MAX + 1`).*

Comment: @chqrlie According to Steve's answer, this conversion is not well defined.

Comment: @chqrlie many thanks. but here. due to the divide-by-zero, the value is not finite, so the behaviour is not well defined, which makes this use illegal. Is not it?

Comment: @MathGeek Note that Steve's answer explicitly says " I can't remember, but I'm pretty sure...".  The only way to be sure is to cite language from the Standard, as chqrlie  does here.